# Multiple required fields in angular JS

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have a new profile form that has multiple required fields, email, password and confirm password. The submit button is set to be disabled if the form is in invalid state. I believe that form should remain in invalid state until user has filled in all the required fields. To my surprise, angular checks my first field only. If it is alone in valid state, submit button gets activated, regardless of states of other fields. I am using angular 1.0.7. What is the reason behind this behavior ?

```
<form name='newProfileForm' ng-submit="formSubmit(newProfileForm.$valid)" novalidate>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login Information</legend>      
        </fieldset>
        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mail" required>
            <p ng-show="newProfileForm.email.$invalid && newProfileForm.email.$dirty">Please enter valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" required/>          
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <select class="span3">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country</label>
            <select class="span3">
            </select>       
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>State</label>
            <select class="span3">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>City</label>
            <select class="span3">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Pin Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select class="span3">
                <option label="Male" value="Male"/>
                <option label="Female" value="Female"/>             
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Field of Interest</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="newProfileForm.$invalid">Submit</button>       
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give ng-model to your password and confirm password field. Do it like

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" ng-model="pass" required/>

<input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpass" ng-model="confirmpass" required/>
```